# Keras: Big one-hot-encoding: binary_crossentropy or categorical_crossentropy

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm training a text classification model where the input data consists of 4096 term frequency–inverse document frequencies.

My output are 416 possible categories. Each piece of data has 3 categories, so there are 3 ones in an array of 413 zeros (one-hot-encodings)

My model looks like this:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2048, activation="relu", input_dim=X.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(416, activation="sigmoid"))
```

When I train it with the `binary_crossentropy` loss, it has a loss of 0.185 and an accuracy of 96% after one epoch. After 5 epochs, the loss is at 0.037 and the accuracy at 99.3%. I guess this is wrong, since there are a lot of 0s in my labels, which it classifies correctly.

When I train it with the `categorical_crossentropy` loss, it has a loss of 15.0 and an accuracy of below 5% in the first few epochs, before it gets stuck at a loss of 5.0 and an accuracy of 12% after several (over 50) epochs.

Which one of those would be right for my situation (large one-hot-encodings with multiple 1s)? What do these scores tell me?

EDIT: These are the `model.compile()` statement:

```python
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and

```python
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: For whoever reviews this post: this is a *coding* issue having to do with Keras, and not one related to stats/ML theory or practice; hence, its place is here, and not in Cross Validated...

Comment: Just curious, why you are using 'sigmoid' instead of the preferred 'softmax' activation in the last layer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: the (high) accuracy reported when you use `loss='binary_crossentropy'` is **not** the correct one, as you already have guessed. For your problem, the recommended loss is `categorical_crossentropy`.

---

In long:

The underlying reason for this behavior is a rather subtle & undocumented issue at how Keras actually *guesses* which accuracy to use, depending on the loss function you have selected, when you include simply `metrics=['accuracy']` in your model compilation, as you have. In other words, while your first compilation option

```python
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
          metrics=['accuracy']
```

is valid, your second one:

```python
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

will not produce what you expect, but the reason is not the use of binary cross entropy (which, at least in principle, is an absolutely valid loss function).

Why is that? If you check the [metrics source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py), Keras does not define a single accuracy metric, but several different ones, among them `binary_accuracy` and `categorical_accuracy`. What happens [under the hood](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L876) is that, since you have selected `loss='binary_crossentropy'` and have not specified a *particular* accuracy metric, Keras (wrongly...) infers that you are interested in the `binary_accuracy`, and this is what it returns - while in fact you are interested in the `categorical_accuracy`.

Let's verify that this is the case, using the [MNIST CNN example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) in Keras, with the following modification:

```python
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])  # WRONG way

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=2,  # only 2 epochs, for demonstration purposes
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

# Keras reported accuracy:
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0) 
score[1]
# 0.9975801164627075

# Actual accuracy calculated manually:
import numpy as np
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
acc = sum([np.argmax(y_test[i])==np.argmax(y_pred[i]) for i in range(10000)])/10000
acc
# 0.98780000000000001

score[1]==acc
# False
```

Arguably, the verification of the above behavior with your own data should be straightforward.

And just for the completeness of the discussion, if, for whatever reason, you insist in using binary cross entropy as your loss function (as I said, nothing wrong with this, at least in principle) while still getting the **categorical** accuracy required by the problem at hand, you should ask explicitly for `categorical_accuracy` in the model compilation as follows:

```python
from keras.metrics import categorical_accuracy
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[categorical_accuracy])
```

In the MNIST example, after training, scoring, and predicting the test set as I show above, the two metrics now are the same, as they should be:

```python
# Keras reported accuracy:
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0) 
score[1]
# 0.98580000000000001

# Actual accuracy calculated manually:
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
acc = sum([np.argmax(y_test[i])==np.argmax(y_pred[i]) for i in range(10000)])/10000
acc
# 0.98580000000000001

score[1]==acc
# True
```

System setup:

```python
Python version 3.5.3
Tensorflow version 1.2.1
Keras version 2.0.4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! It was pointed out to me that `categorical_crossentropy` is not the way to go after all, because I always have to predict 3 ones, whereas `categorical_crossentropy` is expecting a distribution. Is that right? If so, would it be worth to use `binary_crossentropy` with categorical_accuracy?

Comment: @Tutanchamunon As I said, the "canonical" loss when you have multiple classes is the `categorical_crossentropy`; but in the (very poor in theory) deep learning domain, in practice, the ultimate judge is the experiment! So, you can give it a try (with the remedy I have suggested above) and see what you get (and BTW, you could also accept the answer - thanks).